# Apache logs: how many different IPs per day with sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed, logs, apache-httpd

Given a file `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` like this:

```
example.com:443 1.1.1.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 1.1.1.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:10:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 2.2.2.2 - - [25/Jan/2021:12:20:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm13 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
...
example.com:443 33.33.33.33 - - [12/Apr/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm14 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
example.com:443 4.4.4.4 - - [13/Apr/2021:12:00:00 +0000] "GET /abc/def/ghi?token=jklm12 HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel...
```

how to get (or count the number of) the distinct IPs per day?

Example:

```
 25/Jan/2021
     1.1.1.1
     2.2.2.2
 12/Apr/2021
     33.33.33.33
 13/Apr/2021
     4.4.4.4
```

or

```
 25/Jan/2021  2
 12/Apr/2021  1
 13/Apr/2021  1
```

How to do the "group by day"?

Comment: Using `awk`, I would create a [two-dimensional associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multidimensional) indexed by date. Each date gets an associative array of IP addresses. As an added feature, this approach also yields the number of accesses per IP address. Your second output can be achieved by counting the number of IP addresses per date in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<infile awk -F'[[ :]' '{
    dt[$7]=(dt[$7]==""?"":dt[$7]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t" $3:ORS) }
END{ for(d in dt)print d ORS dt[d] }'
```

`(dt[$7]==""?"":dt[$7])` print previous content of the array *dt* if not empty.
`(!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t" $3:ORS)` print *IP*($3) (with a Tab prefix) if not previously seen for that *DTAE*($7), else print a newline (default ORS).

that is updating the `dt[$7]= ...` content of each DATE($7) with the values of above result.

---

```
25/Jan/2021
        1.1.1.1
        2.2.2.2
13/Apr/2021
        4.4.4.4
12/Apr/2021
        33.33.33.33
```

---

to sort the output (input data must be in sorted order on the *date*, most likely logs more often are sorted based on the date):

```
<infile awk -F'[[ :]' '{
    dt[$7]=(dt[$7]==""?"\0"NR"-" $7 ORS:dt[$7]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t" $3:ORS) 
}
END{ for(d in dt) print dt[d] }' |sort -z |cut -z -d'-' -f2-
```

or with GNU awk for the sorting options on the arrays:

```
<infile awk -F'[[ :]' '!date[$7]++{ ind++ }
    { dt[ind]=(dt[ind]==""?$7 ORS:dt[ind]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t" $3:ORS)
}
END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for(d in dt) print dt[d] }'
```

---

```
25/Jan/2021
        1.1.1.1
        2.2.2.2
12/Apr/2021
        33.33.33.33
13/Apr/2021
        4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Would you know of a way to make `awk` understand human-readable dates for the sorting? Making a date-sorted output seems quite strugglesome to me.

Comment: Strangely, it works with this demo data, but not with the real `other_vhost_access.log` file: there are just IPs and lots of blank lines in he the middle. Any idea?

Comment: @FelixJN no, I didn't see if there is an option for it in awk specifically sorting _"human-readable dates"_ , but possible to sort it by converting them to EPOCH, sort and then convert back to human-readable. however these `25/Jan/2021:12:00:00` are not a valid date, so first need to convert it to valid date, then do sorting thing on them

Comment: @αғsнιη Sometimes there multiple IPs in the same line of the output, and sometimes lots of blank lines. Any idea? PS: can you explain a little bit your command?

Comment: Thanks @αғsнιη! Here is the code which works for me: `awk -F'[[ :]' '{ dt[$7]=(dt[$7]==""?"":dt[$7]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t"$3"\n":"") } END{ for(d in dt)print d ORS dt[d] }' other_vhosts_access.log`. The difference is in `!seen...`.

Comment: Last thing @αғsнιη how to sort the display of `for (d in dt)` by date? it's inside the same month so a standard string sort would be ok.

Comment: @Basj see the edit to sorting the output

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is nearly perfect but there were always unwanted blank lines or sometimes multiple IPs in the same line.

So this slight modification made it work for me:

```
awk -F'[[ :]' '{ dt[$7]=(dt[$7]==""?"":dt[$7]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t"$3"\n":"") } END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for(d in dt)print d ORS dt[d] }' other_vhosts_access.log
```

or this if you want to filter the traffic from a specific domain/page

```
grep "example.com" other_vhosts_access.log |awk -F'[[ :]' '{ dt[$7]=(dt[$7]==""?"":dt[$7]) (!seen[$7,$3]++?"\t"$3"\n":"") } END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for(d in dt)print d ORS dt[d] }'
```

Comment: there is no such difference of the ORS instead of `\n` except if you are parsing a log which is Windows style line feed CRLF maybe?, which is why you see strange output also I have updated my answer to sort the output, so I suggest you to remove your this answer

Comment: For some reason it still produces empty blank lines with your code, and it seems fixed with mine. Maybe because of `...?...:""` instead of `...?...:ORS`?

Comment: what is the output of `file other_vhosts_access.log`? what is the output of the `awk '{ print ORS; exit}' other_vhosts_access.log |od -c`?